# Laravel - setting a published_at attribute

Tags: php, laravel

In my application I have publishable announcements that have an `Announcement` model, here is the schema:

```
Schema::create('announcements', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('message');
    $table->text('message_details');
    $table->string('author');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I also have an `AnnouncementObserver` to observe model changes.

I thought that to set the `published_at` I could use the `updated` event like so:

```
/**
 * Handle the announcement "updated" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Announcement  $announcement
 * @return void
 */
public function updated(Announcement $announcement)
{
    $changes = $announcement->getChanges();

    if ($changes['status'] === 'published') {
        $announcement->published_at = Carbon::now();
    }

    Log::notice("An announcement was updated: {$announcement->title} by: " . auth()->user()->full_name);
}
```

However, this did not updated `published_at`. I didn't do this in updating because I couldn't see a way to determine whether the value had actually changed.

Am I overcomplicating here?

**From feedback**

```
/**
 * Handle the announcement "creating" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Article  $announcement
 * @return void
 */
public function updating(Announcement $announcement)
{
    if ($announcement->isDirty(['status'])) {
        $new_status = $announcement->getDirty('status');

        if ($new_status == 'published') {
            dd('weng');
        }
    }
}
```

However this doesn't quite work...

**Based on the answers given, here's what I ended up with...**

```
/**
 * Handle the announcement "creating" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Announcement  $announcement
 * @return void
 */
public function updating(Announcement $announcement)
{
    // Set published_at when published
    if ($announcement->isDirty('status') && $announcement->status === 'published') {
        $announcement->published_at = now();
    }

    // Set published_at to null when unpublished
    if ($announcement->isDirty('status') && $announcement->status !== 'published') {
        $announcement->published_at = null;
    }
}
```

So, if published status is changed `published_at` becomes `NULL`.

Comment: Are you wanting the date to change ever time an update is made as long as the `status` === 'published' or just the first time?

Comment: Just a side note: having a status *published* is a bit redundant if you already have a published_at field. Just check if the published_at field is not null if you want to query only the published announcements.

Comment: @BramVerstraten Unless the OP has more than just the two statuses.

Comment: Hi guys, I used to just have a published field with 3 statuses and used `updated_at` but the user asked that this thing could be in order of when they were first published, not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `published_at` didn't update is because you didn't call `save()` on the model.

That being said it would be better if you applied this change in the `updating()` method of your `AnnouncementObserver`. You can do this by using the `isDirty()` method and then checking the value on the instance itself:

```
public function updating(Announcement $announcement)
{
    if ($announcement->isDirty('status') && announcement->status === 'published') {
        $announcement->published_at = now();
    }
}
```

Since the `updating` event is triggered after `save()/updated()` but before the data is actually persisted you don't need to call `save()` yourself.

Comment: So, I was overcomplicating, it just felt a bit wrong trying to do this in the controller.

Comment: @JesseOrange No, this would go in your `AnnouncementObserver ` class.

Comment: Oh yes I know, I was just explaining my reasoning for using an Observer. I also didn't realise you could access dirty like a normal array...

Comment: @JesseOrange Yeah, you can. I've updated the code to make it simpler as well so you don't actually need to check the array, you're just checking to see if the value is dirty and then checking what the value is.

Comment: To ensure it was status that was updated would you also add isDirty('status')?

Comment: @JesseOrange Yes, that was an oversight on my part haha.

Comment: To be honest I'd never really though about how the dirty method works but looking at it, it now all makes sense as to why theres an array called original.

Comment: @JesseOrange Did this answer your question or are you still needing help with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is change it back to `updating` and check whether or not the announcement was changed using `$announcement->isDirty()`. This method will return true if one or more attributes have changed on the object since it's attributes where retrieved from the database.

Comment: is it possible to do if($announcement->isDirty('status') === 'value')?

Comment: You can use it like this: `if ( $announcement->isDirty(['message_details','status']) )` This checks wether one of the two given attributes has changed and if so it returns true. A string (`'status'`) like you did is possible as well and checks for a single changed attribute. ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_isDirty))

Comment: Given this can you check that the dirty attribute is a given value?

Comment: @JesseOrange if it has to be the `status`, you can do this: `if ( $announcement->isDirty( 'status' ) && $announcement->status === 'the_value_you_want' )`.